# How to display percentage(probability) field in lightning datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I want to display probability field in lightning datatable which is already calculated as percentage. But two extra zeros are getting added at end of every value. data type for column is percent. How can I stop this calculation and display values as is.
ex probability 70 displaying 7000

Comment: Please share the code, guessing in the dark without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [lightning formatted number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/example) and use the percentage like

```
<lightning-formatted-number value={value} format-style="percent"></lightning-formatted-number>
```

Comment: How to use formatter in datatable?

Comment: here is one example from a working solution of mine: 
       `<td>
       <div class="slds-truncate" if:true={clientData.totalsForAccount.annuityLoan} title={clientData.totalsForAccount.annuityLoan}>
        <lightning-formatted-number value={clientData.totalsForAccount.annuityLoan} format-style="decimal" maximum-fraction-digits="1" minimum-fraction-digits="1"></lightning-formatted-number>
       </div>
       <div class="slds-truncate centered-text" if:false={clientData.totalsForAccount.annuityLoan}>-</div>
      </td>`

Comment: How to use in this<template>
    <lightning-datatable
        data="{data}"
        columns="{columns}"
        key-field="id"
        onrowselection="{getSelectedName}"
    >
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>

Comment: not really possible. you should transform your datatable in a slds table and everything should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Solution I have done:
import percentfixed from './percentfixed.html';

```
export default class MyDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        percentfixed : {
            template : percentfixed,
        } 
    }
}
```

Then:
percentFixed.html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-formatted-number value={value} format-style="percent-fixed" maximum-fraction-digits="2"></lightning-formatted-number>
</template>
```

then you can use you new datatable component with new type percentFixed on column.

Comment: How do I use this on my datatable. js and html?